# Книга по программированию ASP .NET MVC 4 на VS 2012

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, книги

Друзья! Подскажите, пожалуйста, книгу по программированию *ASP.NET MVC 4* на *VS 2012* на русском языке, если таковые уже имеются. Спасибо!

Comment: вроде 4 еще нет, 3 есть на русском.

Comment: Помимо того, что вам уже предложили еще есть очень классный цикл статей на хабре, начало тут: http://habrahabr.ru/post/175999/
Там же есть ссылка на вордовский файл со всеми уроками.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Могу посоветовать онлайн-книгу по ASP.NET MVC 4 - http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc/index.php

больше на русском не встречал.

На английском уже есть три книги. Кроме вышеописанной в предыдущем посте:
[Programming ASP.NET MVC 4: Developing Real-World Web Applications with ASP.NET MVC](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-ASP-NET-MVC-Developing-Applications/dp/1449320317/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1352899526&sr=8-4&keywords=asp+net+mvc+4)
и
[ASP.NET MVC 4 in Action](http://www.amazon.com/ASP-NET-MVC-Action-Jeffrey-Palermo/dp/1617290416/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1352899526&sr=8-7&keywords=asp+net+mvc+4)

Первая печатная книга на русском языке по этой теме выйдет только в следующем году

Comment: Благодарю, очень помогло!

Answer (score 3):

На русском пока не найти.
На английском языке можете поискать что-то типа такого: [Professional ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.amazon.com/Professional-ASP-NET-MVC-Jon-Galloway/dp/111834846X/)

Answer (score 3):

1. [ASP.NET MVC 4](http://smarly.net/pro-asp-net-mvc-4) - Адам Фриман
2. [ASP.NET MVC 4 в действии](http://smarly.net/asp-net-mvc-4-in-action) - Джеффри Палермо

Answer (score 2):

На русском языке издана книга O'Reilly Media: «***[ASP.NET MVC 4: разработка реальных веб-приложений с помощью ASP.NET MVC](http://shtonda.blogspot.com/2012/08/programming-asp-net-mvc-4.html)***», Джесс Чедвик, Тодд Снайдер, Хришикеш Панда, бумага офсетная-белая, твердый переплет, 432 стр., ISBN 978-5-8459-1841-3, «ВИЛЬЯМС», 2013

Answer (score 1):

Не могу не посоветовать видео курс [Разработка веб-приложений с использованием ASP.NET MVC Framework](http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/527/383/info). Правда это про MVC 2 и это не книга, но лектор интересно рассказывает.